# Boost 1.56 with QT creator, "LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-gd-1_56.lib'"

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qt-creator, qt5

I am working on a project of boost unit testing framework using QT creator. I have written a small test program and trying to link `libboost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-gd-1_56.lib`. This library is present at specified path. But program fails to compile giving said linking error.

I searched on net and found that, error should go with `#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`. But then, I am getting below error:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::unit_test::test_suite * __cdecl init_unit_test_suite(int,char * * const)" (?init_unit_test_suite@@YAPAVtest_suite@unit_test@boost@@HQAPAD@Z) referenced in function _main
```

The above function is a part of `libboost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-gd-1_56.lib`.

I have written same unit tests using VS 2010 and with the same boost libraries. The program worked properly with expected behavior.

What could be possibly going wrong with the usage of boost on QT?

Comment: I just faced the same problem. Did you get an answer yet?

Comment: If Qt Creator uses MinGW as the compiler... that's the problem. MinGW doesn't work with **.lib** files, only **.a** files. In that case, you need to compile Boost with MinGW to generate the **.a** files.

Comment: and how do I do that? @karlphillip

Comment: @karlphillip MinGW works perfectly with `*.lib` ([proof](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use)). Looking at `error: LNK2019` I can say that it's not MinGW anyway.

Comment: @BurninatorDor show us your project file(s) and some code

Comment: @Drop: I just added my code to the edit. And the rest of it is exactly as the OP described (adding `#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the test module initialization function. Have you defined `BOOST_TEST_MAIN` or `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` before you include the UTF header?

> To automatically generate an empty test module initialization function you need to define BOOST_TEST_MAIN before including the boost/test/unit_test.hpp header. The value of this define is ignored. Alternatively you can define the macro BOOST_TEST_MODULE to be equal to any string (not necessarily in quotes). This macro causes the same result as BOOST_TEST_MAIN, and in addition the macro value becomes the name of the master test suite.
>
> For a test module consisting of multiple source files you have to define these flags in a single test file only. Otherwise you end up with multiple instances of the initialization function.

More info here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/initialization.html